# r function "write.csv" not attaching file extension

Tags: r, csv

I have a `for` loop that runs summary statistics for every census tract in my area, and I need them to be outputted into a folder as a csv file. The loop works however the output files is of type "file".

I also want to combine all said files into one dataframe so that I have one file with the summary statistics for all of the census tracts. I found a "multi merge" function, but it is not working properly and I think it has to do with the fact that my file types are not csv's. My code chunk is below:

```
########################################################################################
## create tables with summary statistic's###############################################
########################################################################################

setwd("C:/Data/nih/data/output/csv/merge")            #choose destination folder

for (result in esc.micro@results){
  print(as.character(result$areaid))                  #print each file name into console as script runs
  census.name <- as.character(result$areaid)          #derive census tract from area ID

  #create table for each census tract using summary statistics
  table.unique <- c(mean(result$selection$BMI, na.rm = TRUE),sum(result$selection$female), sum(result$selection$male), 
                   sum(result$selection$diabet),sum(result$selection$white), sum(result$selection$black),
                   sum(result$selection$indian), sum(result$selection$asian), sum(result$selection$pacific),
                   sum(result$selection$other), sum(result$selection$mixed))
  table.unique <- c(census.name,table.unique)         #combine census tract as column to summary stats
  col.names <- c("areaID","BMI","female","male","diabet","white","black","indian","asian","pacific","other","mixed")
  table.unique <- as.numeric(table.unique)   
  table.unique <-as.data.frame(t(table.unique))       #turn comlums into rows
  names(table.unique) <- col.names                    #add column names
  write.csv(table.unique, file = census.name)         #write csv to output folder
}

#merge all files into single data frame

multmerge = function(mypath){
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=TRUE)})
  Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, datalist)
}

all.tracts <- multmerge("C:/Data/nih/data/output/csv/merge")
```

The code works in that it outputs files to the output folder, and they are comma separated when opened in excel, but the only way to do that is to go and manually add the .csv to the end of the name, which defeats the purpose of a loop. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Try `write.csv(table.unique, file = paste(census.name,".csv",sep=""))`

Comment: Nowhere does `write.csv` say it will change the file name you provide. If you want the `.csv` extension, include it in the file name you give to `write.csv`.

Comment: @ d.b That worked great! Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write.csv` does not automatically add the extension to the file you save. You need to provide complete filename (or filepath if you wish) yourself.

Try using the following in your code where we add `.csv` to census.name using `paste`

```
write.csv(table.unique, file = paste(census.name,".csv",sep=""))
```

Answer (score 1):

The file you are writing will be formatted as a .csv, but without the extension.

In order to get the extension, you will need to paste `".csv"` to the `file =` argument of `write.csv`

In particular:

`write.csv(table.unique, file = census.name)`

Must be changed to:

`write.csv(table.unique, file = paste(census.name, ".csv", sep = ''))`

This code will include the `.csv` extension on the `census.name` string:

```
########################################################################################
## create tables with summary statistic's###############################################
########################################################################################

setwd("C:/Data/nih/data/output/csv/merge")            #choose destination folder

for (result in esc.micro@results){
  print(as.character(result$areaid))                  #print each file name into console as script runs
  census.name <- as.character(result$areaid)          #derive census tract from area ID

  #create table for each census tract using summary statistics
  table.unique <- c(mean(result$selection$BMI, na.rm = TRUE),sum(result$selection$female), sum(result$selection$male), 
                   sum(result$selection$diabet),sum(result$selection$white), sum(result$selection$black),
                   sum(result$selection$indian), sum(result$selection$asian), sum(result$selection$pacific),
                   sum(result$selection$other), sum(result$selection$mixed))
  table.unique <- c(census.name,table.unique)         #combine census tract as column to summary stats
  col.names <- c("areaID","BMI","female","male","diabet","white","black","indian","asian","pacific","other","mixed")
  table.unique <- as.numeric(table.unique)   
  table.unique <-as.data.frame(t(table.unique))       #turn comlums into rows
  names(table.unique) <- col.names                    #add column names
  write.csv(table.unique, file = paste(census.name,".csv", sep=''))         #write csv to output folder
}

#merge all files into single data frame

multmerge = function(mypath){
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=TRUE)})
  Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, datalist)
}

all.tracts <- multmerge("C:/Data/nih/data/output/csv/merge")
```